# Não devo exibir resultados negativos

Tags: sql, query, pl-sql

Montei uma query aonde trago algumas informações, dentre essas informações a ultima coluna retorna valores positivos, negativos e zerados.

Eu não quero que exiba as linhas com valores negativos, porém não estou sabendo fazer isto.

Está é a Query

```
SELECT C.SG_CONCESSIONARIO,
       A.NU_SG,
       A.NU_CHASSI,
       V.DS_NOME_MODELO,
       V.CD_MODELO_GARANTIA,
       B.CD_PECA_APLICADA,
       P.DS_PECA_IDIOMA1,
       P.QT_VENDA_MINIMA,
       (FN_RETORNA_QTD(B.CD_PECA_APLICADA, M.BOOK_NO, M.PAGE_NO)) AS QTD_CATALOGO,
       B.PR_PECA_ORIGINAL AS VL_UNITARIO,
       B.QT_PECA as QTD_SOLICITADO,
       (B.PR_PECA_ORIGINAL *
       (FN_RETORNA_QTD(B.CD_PECA_APLICADA, M.BOOK_NO, M.PAGE_NO))) AS PRECO_CAT,
       ((B.PR_PECA_ORIGINAL + B.VL_ICMS) * B.QT_PECA) AS PRECO_GAR,
       ((B.PR_PECA_ORIGINAL + B.VL_ICMS) * B.QT_PECA) -
       (B.PR_PECA_ORIGINAL *
       (FN_RETORNA_QTD(B.CD_PECA_APLICADA, M.BOOK_NO, M.PAGE_NO))) AS PRECO_DIF
  FROM GARANTIA A
  LEFT JOIN GARANTIA_PC B
    on A.NU_ORDEM_SERVICO = B.NU_ORDEM_SERVICO
   AND A.NU_SEQ_ORDEM_SERVICO = B.NU_SEQ_ORDEM_SERVICO
   AND A.CD_CONCESSIONARIO = B.CD_CONCESSIONARIO
  LEFT JOIN VEICULO V
    ON A.NU_CHASSI = V.NU_CHASSI
  LEFT JOIN MODEL_MASTER O
    ON v.cd_catalogo = O.CD_PRODUCAO
  LEFT JOIN PECA P
    ON B.CD_PECA_APLICADA = P.CD_PECA
  LEFT JOIN CAT_H5J021D K
    ON O.Illust_Pn = K.Illust_Pn
  LEFT JOIN CAT_H5J024D M
    ON K.BOOK_NO = M.BOOK_NO
   AND B.CD_PECA_APLICADA = M.PART_NO,
CONCESSIONARIO C   
 WHERE A.DT_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
   AND B.DT_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
   AND C.DT_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
   AND A.CD_CONCESSIONARIO = C.ID_CONCESSIONARIO
   AND A.CD_TIPO_GARANTIA != 'C'
   AND A.DT_INCLUSAO BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/07/2015', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND
       TO_DATE('02/07/2015', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
 order by NU_CHASSI, CD_PECA_APLICADA, M.BOOK_NO, M.PAGE_NO
```

Função FN_RETORNA_QTD

```
create or replace function FN_RETORNA_QTD(peca     in varchar2,
                                          catalogo in varchar2,
                                          page_no  in varchar2)
  return varchar2 is

  v_qtd number(2);

begin

  select qtd
    into v_qtd
    from (select M.QTY_1 as qtd
            from CAT_H5J024D M
           WHERE PART_NO = peca
             and m.book_no = catalogo
             and M.QTY_1 is not null
             and M.QTY_1 != 'AR'
             and M.PAGE_NO = page_no
          union
          select M.QTY_2 as qtd
            from CAT_H5J024D M
           WHERE PART_NO = peca
             and m.book_no = catalogo
             and M.QTY_2 is not null
             and M.QTY_2 != 'AR'
             and M.PAGE_NO = page_no
          union
          select M.QTY_3 as qtd
            from CAT_H5J024D M
           WHERE PART_NO = peca
             and m.book_no = catalogo
             and M.QTY_3 is not null
             and M.QTY_3 != 'AR'
             and M.PAGE_NO = page_no
          union
          select M.QTY_4 as qtd
            from CAT_H5J024D M
           WHERE PART_NO = peca
             and m.book_no = catalogo
             and M.QTY_4 is not null
             and M.QTY_4 != 'AR'
             and M.PAGE_NO = page_no
          union
          select M.QTY_5 as qtd
            from CAT_H5J024D M
           WHERE PART_NO = peca
             and m.book_no = catalogo
             and M.QTY_5 is not null
             and M.QTY_5 != 'AR'
             and M.PAGE_NO = page_no
             )
   where rownum = 1;

  return(v_qtd);

end FN_RETORNA_QTD;
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar o `(FN_RETORNA_QTD(B.CD_PECA_APLICADA, M.BOOK_NO, M.PAGE_NO))) >= 0` no where?

Comment: Tentei, mas ainda sim retornam os resultados negativos

Comment: A função FN_RETORNA_QTD pode retonar valores negativos?

Comment: A FN_RETORNA_QTD não retorna nenhum valor negativo. O que ela faz é informar a quantidade minima de peças utilizada em cada veículo de acordo com o catálogo em que a peça se encontra. 
Estou incluindo a função na pergunta.

Comment: Outra pergunta @Igor, B.VL_ICMS e B.QT_PECA podem ser negativos?

Comment: Também não, os valores que retornam nesses itens é 0 ou maior. Somente a ultima coluna aonde é feito a conta de O preço da qtd_min do catalogo * preço da peça menos a qtd usada na garantia * preço que pode ser negativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão que calcula o PRECO_DIF pode ser simplificada para:

```
B.PR_PECA_ORIGINAL*(B.QT_PECA + B.VL_ICMS - FN_RETORNA_QTD(B.CD_PECA_APLICADA, M.BOOK_NO, M.PAGE_NO))
```

Isso mostra que não basta fazer B.PR_PECA_ORIGINAL >= 0 ou FN_RETORNA_QTD >=0, já que se o resultado retornado pela FN_RETORNA_QTD for maior do que a soma entre B.QT_PECA + B.VL_ICMS, então o preço será negativo.

Neste caso, portanto, você pode incluir a seguinte expressão na sua clausula Where:

```
AND (B.QT_PECA + B.VL_ICMS - FN_RETORNA_QTD(B.CD_PECA_APLICADA, M.BOOK_NO, M.PAGE_NO)) >= 0
```

Uma outra solução seria criar uma tabela temporária com o resultado do SQL e depois fazer uma SQL nessa tabela WHERE PRECO_DIF >= 0.

Outra solução é colocar esse SQL dentro de outro e na clásula WHERE do SQL mais externo fazer PRECO_DIF >= 0.

Comment: Funcionou certinho adicionando o AND >=0. Também ficou mais limpo essa forma de calcular o PRECO_DIF. 
Obrigado !